# Mapbox: How to add a Hexbins visualisation?

Tags: angular, mapbox

I'm working on an Angular 4 project for visualisation of a huge amount of data with mapbox, I need to provide different visualisations. now I'm trying to work with Hexbins but I can't find any simple tutorials about it. 
I need a basic example for beginners. Your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Mapbox works with Geojson sources which are not aware of specific "shapes" (such as a hexagon); only points, lines and polygons.

So you could use **Turf.js** which has a function that converts a bounding box to a hexagonal grid: [`hexGrid`](http://turfjs.org/docs/#hexGrid):

```
const bbox = [-96,31,-84,40];
const cellSide = 50;
const options = { units: 'miles' };

const hexgrid = turf.hexGrid(bbox, cellSide, options);
const source = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": hexgrid
}
```

Full demo: https://codepen.io/eddydg/pen/erEydr

Comment: thank you for your answer, do you have a complete example that I can follow?

Comment: There isn't much more to it, you just need to replace the `bbox` with your bounding box and use `source` as your layer source. I added a Codepen demo.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm getting the same result as you but I need to visualise separated points with different opacity levels related to the density, any idea about it?

Comment: Use data-driven styling : you have the `fill-opacity` property, and then you can use a linear interpolation to have a 0.5 opacity if density is 0, and 1 opacity if density is 1:

 `{ "fill-opacity": ["interpolate", ["linear"], ["DENSITY_PROPERTY"], 0, 0.5, 1, 1] }`

https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#expressions-ramps-scales-curves

Comment: Thank you, I tried it but it's not working. Actually I'm trying to get something like this. https://www.google.de/search?q=hexbins+visualisation&tbm=isch&tbs=rimg:CUioHXZ-BLPiIjgeKLzcpHPPwfYoNg9WNoE9M76WVhwvcfe4OQuFlAe-PqY23FFuhqznN6hg86UOrYLHCabKIEmhfCoSCR4ovNykc8_1BESAAkiz22XyUKhIJ9ig2D1Y2gT0RwkWETvbhwCsqEgkzvpZWHC9x9xEVliYvMx9hSioSCbg5C4WUB74-ERNb-4D0NZ4pKhIJpjbcUW6GrOcRjT5ONnzB1h8qEgk3qGDzpQ6tghHAmtDWtM85nSoSCccJpsogSaF8EXhduqS_1hpvA&tbo=u&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi8zJS1q_PaAhUD3KQKHY4kBLYQ9C96BAgBEBs&biw=1166&bih=646&dpr=2#imgrc=N6hg86UOrYJe1M:

Comment: What do you mean it's not working? Did you replace `DENSITY_PROPERTY` with the property's key in your `source` that contains the density value? Don't forget to check if there are any errors in the console and to take a look at the many data-driven/expressions examples in the Mapbox style specs.

Comment: Thank you so much, now It's working but I was thinking about having separate points, not only a bloc of points inside the Bbox

Comment: Here is an example of what I try to make: http://jsfiddle.net/reblace/acjnbu8t/   But I want to provide my source as a result of a GET request.

Comment: If you can use it as is (with Leaflet and D3js), you can just replace the `generateData()` by a `fetch()` call to your source, format it if necessary to have an array of [lng, lat], and finally call `hexLayer.data` with it. Otherwise, if you have to use Mapbox it's a bit more complicated and will probably have to use something like Mapbox Supercluster https://github.com/mapbox/supercluster

Comment: Yes I have to use mapbox, I have made a clusters visualisation already but now I'm trying to make a hexbins one.